# Is possible to put a PFET before a DCDC step up converter?

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, raspberry-pi

I have the following schematic:
3.7V battery --> DCDC step up converter to regulated 5V USB --> Raspberry Pi Zero.

I want to be able to cut the power supply with a MOSFET, I have to use a P-channel. When I put it after the DCDC converter, no issues, all works fine except for the voltage drop due to RDS resitance.

When I try to put the MOSFET before the DCDC and I plug in the Raspberry Pi, then the DCDC goes off and nothing works.

Why is this happening? How could I solve this? What is the best approach? Is the choice of this P-channel OK?

Please find the circuit attached:

[image: schematics]

Comment: Where is the 3.3V coming from?

Comment: Where's ground on the supply? Why do you write 3'3 and not 3,3 or 3.3?

Comment: I can’t find any other information about the IRF940 except that it ever existed and was used by someone. :)
Does anyone have information about it?

Comment: The 3.3v is comming from an RTC module

Comment: find the datasheet here: http://www.redrok.com/MOSFET_IRF9540N_-100V_-23A_117mO_Vth-4.0_TO-220.pdf

Comment: Thanks. This one should do [nicely](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/NDP6020P/NDP6020P-ND/1055922). You need a logic level PMOS for this.

Comment: @Csabahu Seems to be overkill for this application. I'd suggest Si2333DS-T1-GE3 if it is as low power as it looks. Rds(on) of 0.03ohm @ Vg(th) = -2.5V

Comment: @MatBE Yes, you are right, I was just looking for a traditional one, not an SMT design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lack of information to help you resolve this issue properly.

Is the P/N for the PMOS even correct? I'm not able to locate datasheet for IRF940N

**If** it's IRF9540 instead, then following applies:

You are operating the PMOS just on the border of the specified threshold voltage.  It tells you that a conductive channel is created somewhere within that range. Not that it's fully open. And since you are working with -3.7V(th) the reason could be the input voltage for the DC-DC isn't high enough and therefore unable to operate due to the voltage drop caused by the on-resistance of the PMOS. But i wouldn't know without a datasheet.
[image]

Comment: Thanks in advance, I see your point. The datasheets is in the following link: http://www.redrok.com/MOSFET_IRF9540N_-100V_-23A_117mO_Vth-4.0_TO-220.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen a poor MOSFET for this application if you have the [IRF9540](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91078/91078.pdf). I say this
because your diagram says IRF940 and I think this might be a typo: -

[image]

The graph above doesn't even consider activating the gate at voltages below -4.5 volts because it just isn't a reliable device to use at these voltages. I would choose a more appropriate device.

With the sort of gate voltage you are trying to use, the ON resistance of the MOSFET is going to be an ohm or two at best and probably a showstopper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration. Here, the Gate of the PFET is connected to the Source of the PFET which is connected to the Drain of an NFET. The NFET will pull the Gate of the PFET to 0V when the NFET is conductive. When that happens, that will allow the PFET to conduct.[image]